# Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

hello please help me when i connect my phone to android studio i am getting this type of log it was working fine few days ago after i update my android studio i am unable to connect my physically devices i tried everything delete android studio remove it everything and the intsall  it again even install older version but error was same i don't know  why it was happening suddenly.while connecting my window it was working fine but on mac i am getting this error

```
09/05/2023
9:38 PM Adb connection Error:EOF
9:38 PM Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
9:38 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:38 PM * daemon started successfully
9:38 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:38 PM * daemon started successfully
9:38 PM Adb connection Error:EOF
9:38 PM Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
9:38 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:38 PM * daemon started successfully
9:38 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:38 PM * daemon started successfully
9:38 PM Adb connection Error:EOF
9:38 PM Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
9:38 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:38 PM * daemon started successfully
9:38 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:38 PM * daemon started successfully
9:38 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:38 PM * daemon started successfully
9:38 PM Adb connection Error:EOF
9:38 PM Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
9:38 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:38 PM * daemon started successfully
9:38 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:38 PM * daemon started successfully
9:38 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:38 PM * daemon started successfully
9:38 PM Adb connection Error:EOF
9:38 PM Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
9:38 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:38 PM * daemon started successfully
9:38 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:38 PM * daemon started successfully
9:38 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:38 PM * daemon started successfully
9:39 PM Adb connection Error:EOF
9:39 PM Sending jdwp tracking request failed!
9:39 PM Failed to start monitoring DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI
9:39 PM Cannot reach ADB server, attempting to reconnect.
9:39 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:39 PM ADB server didn't ACK
9:39 PM Full server startup log:
/var/folders/91/hm2yhm515qqg8wm5zzsz4dnm0000gn/T//adb.501.log
9:39 PM Server had pid: 1108
9:39 PM --- adb starting (pid 1108) ---
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 main.cpp:63] Android Debug
Bridge version 1.0.41
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 main.cpp:63] Version
34.0.1-9680074
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 main.cpp:63] Installed as
/Users/joshua/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 main.cpp:63] 
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:237]
Openscreen mdns discovery enabled
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16806 usb_osx.cpp:315] reported max
packet size for DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI is 512
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 auth.cpp:416]
adb_auth_init...
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 auth.cpp:152] loaded new key
from '/Users/joshua/.android/adbkey' with fingerprint
C9EB1915203476FB76DBC89FC2E5F4F5246CB85A5290D2263856992316D0AF14
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16810 transport.cpp:335]
DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI: read thread spawning
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16811 transport.cpp:307]
DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI: write thread spawning
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:659] UDP
socket created for 0.0.0.0:5353
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:170]
AdbUdpSocket fd=9
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:659] UDP
socket created for [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:170]
AdbUdpSocket fd=11
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:274]
SetMulticastOutboundInterface for index=5
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:72]
Encountered fatal discovery error: Failure: SocketBindFailure =
"endpoint: 0.0.0.0:5353"
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:513] adb_bind
failed: Address already in use
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:72]
Encountered fatal discovery error: Failure: SocketOptionSettingFailure
= "endpoint: 0.0.0.0:5353"
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:343]
adb_setsockopt failed
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:72]
Encountered fatal discovery error: Failure: SocketOptionSettingFailure
= "endpoint: 0.0.0.0:5353"
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:351]
adb_setsockopt failed
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:274]
SetMulticastOutboundInterface for index=5
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:72]
Encountered fatal discovery error: Failure: SocketBindFailure =
"endpoint: [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353"
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:538] adb_bind
failed: Address already in use
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:72]
Encountered fatal discovery error: Failure: SocketOptionSettingFailure
= "endpoint: [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353"
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:369]
adb_setsockopt failed
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:72]
Encountered fatal discovery error: Failure: SocketOptionSettingFailure
= "endpoint: [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353"
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:369]
adb_setsockopt failed
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:659] UDP
socket created for [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:170]
AdbUdpSocket fd=10
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:274]
SetMulticastOutboundInterface for index=10
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:72]
Encountered fatal discovery error: Failure: SocketBindFailure =
"endpoint: [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353"
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:538] adb_bind
failed: Address already in use
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:72]
Encountered fatal discovery error: Failure: SocketOptionSettingFailure
= "endpoint: [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353"
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:369]
adb_setsockopt failed
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:72]
Encountered fatal discovery error: Failure: SocketOptionSettingFailure
= "endpoint: [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353"
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:369]
adb_setsockopt failed
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:659] UDP
socket created for [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353
9:39 PM '/Users/joshua/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:170]
AdbUdpSocket fd=10
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:274]
SetMulticastOutboundInterface for index=11
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:72]
Encountered fatal discovery error: Failure: SocketBindFailure =
"endpoint: [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353"
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:538] adb_bind
failed: Address already in use
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:72]
Encountered fatal discovery error: Failure: SocketOptionSettingFailure
= "endpoint: [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353"
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:369]
adb_setsockopt failed
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:72]
Encountered fatal discovery error: Failure: SocketOptionSettingFailure
= "endpoint: [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353"
9:39 PM adb E 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 udp_socket.cpp:369]
adb_setsockopt failed
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport_mdns.cpp:187]
Fallback to MdnsResponder client for discovery
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 transport.cpp:1727] fetching
keys for transport DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 auth.cpp:468] Calling
send_auth_response
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:15  1108 16803 adb.cpp:176]
DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI: offline
9:39 PM * failed to start daemon
9:39 PM error: cannot connect to daemon
9:39 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
9:39 PM ADB server didn't ACK
9:39 PM Full server startup log:
/var/folders/91/hm2yhm515qqg8wm5zzsz4dnm0000gn/T//adb.501.log
9:39 PM Server had pid: 1112
9:39 PM --- adb starting (pid 1112) ---
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:16  1112 16833 main.cpp:63] Android Debug
Bridge version 1.0.41
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:16  1112 16833 main.cpp:63] Version
34.0.1-9680074
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:16  1112 16833 main.cpp:63] Installed as
/Users/joshua/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:16  1112 16833 main.cpp:63] 
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:16  1112 16833 transport_mdns.cpp:237]
Openscreen mdns discovery enabled
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:16  1112 16839 usb_osx.cpp:315] reported max
packet size for DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI is 512
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:16  1112 16833 auth.cpp:416]
adb_auth_init...
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:16  1112 16833 auth.cpp:152] loaded new key
from '/Users/joshua/.android/adbkey' with fingerprint
C9EB1915203476FB76DBC89FC2E5F4F5246CB85A5290D2263856992316D0AF14
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:16  1112 16842 transport.cpp:335]
DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI: read thread spawning
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:16  1112 16843 transport.cpp:307]
DEHA7PKJFIHQUSBI: write thread spawning
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:16  1112 16833 udp_socket.cpp:659] UDP
socket created for 0.0.0.0:5353
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:16  1112 16833 udp_socket.cpp:170]
AdbUdpSocket fd=10
9:39 PM adb I 05-09 21:39:16  1112 16833 udp_socket.cpp:659] UDP
socket created for [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]:5353
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to restart your phone, check your cable or check the USB port you are using. If problem persists you can try restarting the ADB server using `adb kill-server` then `adb start-server` in your terminal.